# Difference between -webkit , -khtml ,-moz ,-o property in css?

Tags: html, css

what is the difference between -webkit-box-shadow , -khtml-box-shadow , -moz-box-shadow , -o-box-shadow in CSS?

My CSS is like this:

```
button:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 5px;
    -khtml-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 5px;
    -o-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 5px;
```

Comment: here you go http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no immediate differences, it's a vendor prefix in order to tell the different browsers how to interpret, in this case, the property `box-shadow`.
This is done since the different browsers could possibly implement it differently.

The vendor prefixes also allows you to use experimental features or not finalised features.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. These are **CSS vendor prefixes** or **CSS browser prefixe**

> It's a way for browser makers to add support for new CSS features in a
>   sort of testing and experimentation period. Browser prefixes are used
>   to add new features that may not be part of a formal specification and
>   to implement features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized.

```
Android: -webkit-
Chrome: -webkit-
Firefox: -moz-
Internet Explorer: -ms-
iOS: -webkit-
Opera: -o-
Safari: -webkit-
```

[Reference](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. These are vendor prefixes, used for **support**.

When the CSS spec isn't finalized, vendors (browser makers) add prefixes to the CSS rules. It's supposed to prevent problems with the spec changing and incompatibility issues. (not that it actually does, it's just an annoyance)

[Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) (a great resource) has compatibility tables on CSS features. For box-shadow, old Safari and Chrome use `-webkit-`, while old FF uses `-moz-`. The `-o-` and `-khtml-` prefixes don't seem to be necessary.

BTW, even if there is no browser support (there *is* in your case), you should add the standards-compliant rule:

```
button:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That are prefix for older versions of browsers. o for opera, moz for mozilla, etc. You can read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp).

Comment: w3schools is know to provide inaccurate content.

Answer (score 0):

-webkit -khtml -moz -o- are vendor prefix for :

- webkit(safari,browser)
- moz(firefox)
- o(opera)
- khtml(konqueror)

Mainly used for CSS3 features, they sometimes allow to use or change the browser behaviour with "modern" properties.

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/

Answer (score 0):

## **Vendor Prefix**

Browser vendors sometimes add prefixes to experimental or nonstandard CSS properties and JavaScript APIs, so developers can experiment with new ideas while—in theory—preventing their experiments from being relied upon and then breaking web developers' code during the standardization process. Developers should wait to include the unprefixed property until browser behavior is standardized.

> Note: Browser vendors are working to stop using vendor prefixes for
> experimental features. Web developers have been using them on
> production Web sites, despite their experimental nature. This has made
> it more difficult for browser vendors to ensure compatibility and to
> work on new features; it's also been harmful to smaller browsers who
> wind up forced to add other browsers' prefixes in order to load
> popular web sites.
>
> Lately, the trend is to add experimental features behind
> user-controlled flags or preferences, and to create smaller
> specifications which can reach a stable state much more quickly.

## CSS prefixes

The major browsers use the following prefixes:

- `-webkit-` (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera, almost all iOS browsers including Firefox for iOS; basically, any WebKit based
  browser)
- `-moz-` (Firefox)
- `-o-` (old pre-WebKit versions of Opera)
- `-ms-` (Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge)

Sample usage:

```
-webkit-transition: all 4s ease;
-moz-transition: all 4s ease;
-ms-transition: all 4s ease;
-o-transition: all 4s ease;
transition: all 4s ease;
```

## API prefixes

Historically, vendors have also used prefixes for experimental APIs. If an entire interface is experimental, then the interface's name is prefixed (but not the properties or methods within). If an experimental property or method is added to a standardized interface, then the individual method or property is prefixed.

### Interface prefixes

Prefixes for interface names are upper-cased:

- `WebKit` (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera, almost all iOS
  browsers (including Firefox for iOS); basically, any WebKit based
  browser)
- `Moz` (Firefox)
- `O` (Older, pre-WebKit, versions of Opera)
- `MS` (Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge)

### Property and method prefixes

The prefixes for properties and methods are lower-case:

- `webkit` (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera, almost all iOS
  browsers (including Firefox for iOS); basically, any WebKit based
  browser)
- `moz` (Firefox)
- `o` (Old, pre-WebKit, versions of Opera)
- `ms` (Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge)

Sample usage:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
```

The documentation took from this RESOURCE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Answer (score -1):

Default: (none)
Android: -webkit-
Chrome: -webkit-
Firefox: -moz- || -webkit-
Internet Explorer: -ms- || -webkit-
iOS: -webkit-
Opera: -webkit- || -o-
Safari: -webkit-
Konqueror: -khtml-

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.